# Chrome extension dropdown not correct size

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a very simple chrome extension. It is almost entirely based on the [sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted). Sometimes when I click it it works perfectly, sometimes it only drops down a minimal amount.

[image]

This is the minimal drop amount

[image]

And this is it working correctly. (When I say correctly, ignore the fact that it's totally horrendous, that's stage two)

### Question

What do I need to do to ensure that it drops down properly?

Comment: May I see the popup.html? Did you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I didn't have a doctype! I modified the example file and didn't think to add one. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the beginning of the popup.html file. Glad it helps!